# Reorder jquery dataTable after change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm using `jquery dataTable` and after initialization, the sorting works perfectly. However, after I use `ajax` to execute `js` which replaces a row's column value, the sorting still assumes the old order from initialization.

What can I do to reorder a column or the entire table after I change a row's value?

I've tried `.rowReordering()` with `jquery.ui`, but that just made the rows draggable and the sorting broke.

Comment: depends how you change values...if using `aoData` or not. Please create demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates issue